# Transforming map values which are an array of objects with class-tranformer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class-transformer

I have class like this:

```
class ValueType {
  field1: number,
  field2: string
}

class Demo {
  someField: Map<number, ValueType[]>
}
```

How can I transform values of map?

I have tried annotating it with `@Type(() => ValueType)`